# Webhooks on spark-gcp deployed through operatorhub

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-operator

I deployed gcp-spark operator on k8s. Its working perfectly fine. Able to run scala and python jobs with no issues.

But, I am unable to create volume mounts on my pods. Unable to use local fs. Looks like spark-operator should be enabled with webhooks for it to work. Going by [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.md#about-the-mutating-admission-webhook).

There was an spark-operator with webhooks yaml [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/manifest/spark-operator-with-webhook.yaml), but the name is different to the deployment coming through the operator hub. I updated the names to the best of my knowledge and tried to apply the deployment. But ran into the below issue.

```
kubectl apply -f spark-operator-with-webhook.yaml
Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
deployment.apps/spark-operator configured
service/spark-webhook unchanged
The Job "spark-operator-init" is invalid: spec.template: Invalid value: core.PodTemplateSpec{ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVers......int(nil)}}: field is immutable
```

Is there an easy way of enabling webhooks on spark-operator? I want to be able to mount local fs on the sparkapplication. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I purged the init object and redeployed. The manifest was successfully applied.